# Is open source software safe for us?

Tags: security

There are a lot of open source software like Reaver in internet, everyone is able to download and use it. So, my question is about the security of this kind of software, I mean, not just hacking software. Are there back doors on those programs or some like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are safe if only:

1. You read and compile the source by yourself.
2. You use a compiled version which has been read and compiled by someone who you trust. (and/or being watched by a lot of peoples).

Otherwise there is no way to tell a compiled version of a source is exactly same as the source.

For your specific example, "Reaver" is available to be installed using Ubuntu official repositories, Which we all have trust in.

They are being compiled by a dozen of trusted maintainers and being watched by thousands of people.

Also have a look at: https://reproducible-builds.org

But if you grab a copy of a software from any site, or even try to compile a clean source using an unknown build script written by who knows who, that might do anything to your system.

---

Hack and crack tools are one of the most used targets by hackers to infect users, because they're like honey... they claim to hack someone for you and if you don't know what you are really doing they'll going to hack you first for sure.

Comment: You run exactly the same risk with Windows apps if you don't look at their source code or have a trusted expert do that for you.  Oh? Microsoft won't show you their source code? Then they might do anything to your system.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of "safe". Just because the software has no backdoors, does not mean that it has no potential vulnerabilities (i.e. security-related bugs), or it cannot be used in potentially dangerous ways (e.g. ssh agent forwarding)